# How to put ReCaptcha in a popup?

Tags: captcha, recaptcha, modalpopups

I want to show Recaptcha in a Popup.
Like i have a page where the user can submit a note. If someone is submitting a note i want to show a popup where recaptcha control will be there and after validation the note will be submitted.

How can i do that?
Can someone please help.

Comment: What language are you using? What have you tried?