# How to use reCAPTCHA as pop up window instead of part of the web?

Tags: javascript, html, verification, recaptcha

I made a webpage which can provide some direct downloads. Therefore I only want real human, not crawler, to download my files. I tried to use Google reCAPTCHA but it is part of the webpage - visitors can still use the download links and doesn't have to worry about the reCAPTCHA at all. Is there a way to mandate visitors to pass the verification first? For example, is it possible to pop up reCAPTCHA before the whole page is loaded? If that's doable, how can I do it? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Google's reCaptcha to protect download link from bots](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34092288/using-googles-recaptcha-to-protect-download-link-from-bots)

Comment: You could try not generating the links until the user goes through the captcha first, maybe by generating the links via an ajax call or something.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to put ReCaptcha in a popup?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656633/how-to-put-recaptcha-in-a-popup)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I can recommend here is the captcha form be on the current page that you have and create a new page with the download links that's not indexable.

Upon authorizing the captcha code, use header('Location: download.php'); or something similar to redirect the user.

A captcha before loading a webpage is possible, but it always uses client side code such as javascript which bots can easily bypass.